# Generalized vs conjugate momenta

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, definition

For a given Lagrangian $L$, the $i$th generalized [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) is defined as
$$p_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_i}}$$
where $\dot{q_i}$ is the time derivative of the $i$th generalized coordinate (i.e. the $i$th generalized velocity).

I have also seen the above referred to as conjugate momenta, or even generalized conjugate momenta. What exactly is the difference between these terms? Do they all mean the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.
*Generalized* emphasizes the fact that the momenta depend on *generalized* coordinates (therefore, physical dimensions may be different from $M L T^{-1}$), while *conjugate* refers to the definition, connected to the Legendre transform underlying the introduction of the $ p$s, starting from the Lagrangian and the generalized coordinates $q$s.

Comment: +1 Worth adding that it is *conjugate to* corresponding generalized coordinate. It cannot be *conjugate* by itself.

Comment: @RogerVadim Thanks for the comment. I have added a final part of the last sentence.